# Set location of app.config file for interop com object

Tags: vb.net, com

I am creating a windows com object in VS2010 and VB.net (interop)

This com object should be able to work with any NON managed code application such as word, Excel or in this case Access.

The creating of the com object and using regasm etc. works fine. No problem.

However the INSTANT I create a com object that requires connection strings or anything else from the app.config file then it fails.  In this case it happens to be a web service and the common "endpoint" or app.config file could not be found error occurs. (if it was just a connection string I would simply read in this value – but the config file quite messy due to a web service definition).

There is some suggesting that placing the .dll's and app.config in the SAME directory as the office program such as excel then renaming the config file as Excel.exe.config should work.

This does not seem to be working for me.

Is there a means to have the vb.net class (.dll) that is now a com object to know to load + use a config file for the .dll and not some main application file?

Note that in this case I do NOT have a main application config file since I am launching a non managed application like word or Excel and attempting to use my class object.

In vb.net obviously I can copy the config file stuff from the .dll to the main application config and we are off to the races. I don't have a managed "main" file as noted.

So how do I get the class.dll file to load up the class.dll.config file when an instance of the object is created in non managed code?

Answer (score 3):

Using application settings in a class library is in general a poor practice, .NET only supports them for EXE projects.  It is off the chart in the case of a [ComVisible] DLL, you have completely no control over which EXE uses your code.

It's not like it doesn't work, putting a copy of foo.exe.config in the foo.exe client directory works just fine.  Trouble starts when you are not the only one that looked for this solution.  Now installers start to overwrite each other's .config files, your customer loses big time when add-ins fail undiagnosably.

There's just one solution to this problem: don't use settings.  Plenty of other ways to provide config to a class library.  An .xml file in a well known location works just fine as well.

Comment: Appreciate your fair advice. This .exe program is NOT managed code and using regasm and placing .dlls in same dir .exe dir does not work.  Agree changing .exe is problem but my case I do know location of un-manged .exe (msaccess.exe).  Question THEN becomes how to get the class object to read in a known app.config file that now resides in known file location. Problem is not location but figuring out how to get the existing class code to use that existing web service mapping contained in the config file.  Loading via systemConfigManger does not seem to work (even when testing via managed code).

Comment: You are not using my advice.  *Don't* use settings.  So don't use an app.config file either.

Comment: Why when creating an com object instances should such objects not have their own configuration files? Why should 10 different automation clients written in different languages that choose to use such a com object EACH have HUGE WHACKS of code to load complex settings? When I create an instance of a popular com object like OutLook or Word there is HUGE MASSIVE list of settings loaded ranging from user profile, regional settings, default paragraph settings, type of pop email server etc.  This is a long time precedent in our industry but I am all ears if you suggesting something better.

Comment: When I saying a "known" config file location I am agreeing that I should not call that config file app.config but will give it some other name. The issue remains that loading this xml file via system.ConfigManager DOES NOT work. So I 100% agree that I should not use some standard app config file, but problem is HOW to map the existing config file (which I agree is now re-named to something else) REMAINS my problem. So my question assumes I am using some custom XML re-named config file. The file re-name issue is trivial. Having the created object to use the settings is the problem.