# No connection string found, Entity Framework 6, from VBA using COM interop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, vba, com-interop, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to call, from a VBA program (in msaccess), a C# program that makes use of Entity Framework 6. I keep getting this error **ONLY when calling the C# function from VBA by COM interop**, on the line that first uses Entity Framework:

> No connection string named 'myEntities' could be found in the application config file.

I've tried copying app.config to msaccess.exe.config in the same directory as masaccess.exe, but that doesn't solve the issue.  Is there any simple solution?  Thanks.

(There is this, but it wasn't answered.  Existing posts on the subject haven't been helpful.
[Set location of app.config file for interop com object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539663/set-location-of-app-config-file-for-interop-com-object)
)

addendum (added from my comments below):
It doesn't appear that forcing the config location helps EntityFramework 6 out.  I keep getting this error, where "SetttingGet" is my small procedure that makes use of EF dbcontext to look up a value.
(Works fine except when using COM interop with VBA calling C#/.net.)

Error is in private ctor for the C# class called by VBA (and error does NOT occur outside of VBA):This is with same .config files (app.config and MSACCESS.Exe.Config). The error is this (--note that "SettingGet" below is the first use of EntityFramework in my code):

```
The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DefaultInstance() 
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString) 
at MyCode.MyEntities..ctor() in MyCode\MyEntitiesModel.Context.cs:line 18   
at MyCode.MyUtils.SettingGet(String SettingName, String& sVal) in \MyCode\MyCode.cs:line 867 
at MyCode.MyApp..ctor() in \MySln\MyCode\MyCode.cs:line 190
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug your C# code when running from COM Interop and examine `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile`.  That will tell you where it's expecting to find its configuration file.

Comment: Location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE.Config  -- however it doesn't work.

Comment: fwiw I've also tried both debug and release configurations, and both anycpu and x86 variants--always fails to work from vba and works fine in C# (and the only thing that fails in COM interop is any code that makes use of Entity Framework 6).  One would think there would be some way of simply passing the string name of the configuration file to use from VBA to c#?  --I suppose that would be much too easy and convenient to be a possible solution.

Comment: Also have tried changing the config file by using: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", @configFile); --A debug.print shows it uses the new location, but EntityFramework likes it not, and I get the same error. (Where "SettingGet" in the error report is only my small procedure that looks up a value by using entityFramework dbcontext--works fine except if COM interop is being used).